# Is there an asymmetric version of nominal correlation?

Tags: categorical-data, correlation

I use [Cramer's V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) to calculate correlation of features in a dataset made of only nominal features.

Let's consider the following dataset:

```
a  |  b
--------
0  |  0
0  |  1
0  |  0
1  |  2
1  |  2
1  |  3
```

Calculating Cramer's V for features `a` and `b` yields 0.707. Since it's symmetric, there's information loss in this case - as we can see, knowing the value of `b` means we know for sure what is the value of `a`, but this is no the case if we are given the value of `a`; in this case, the number possible values of `b` decreases, but it's still not known for sure.

I'd like to find an asymmetric metric that will provide this information for nominal values - meaning, will give a different value when calculated `a` -> `b` and `b` -> `a`. Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found what I was looking for - it's called [Theil's U](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_coefficient), or the Uncertainty Coefficient.

I've used it in this [Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/shakedzy/alone-in-the-woods-using-theil-s-u-for-survival), you can check it out for an example and code implementation in Python

**EDIT:** I also have a [blogpost](https://medium.com/@shakedzy/the-search-for-categorical-correlation-a1cf7f1888c9) about it.